# Can't figure out BeautifulSoup Command for this HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from this webpage: https://fisheries.msc.org/en/fisheries/@@search Here's the code where I'm running into a problem:

```
results = soup.find(id='results-body')

fisheries = results.find_all('tr', class_='geo-feature fishery')

for fishery in fisheries:
    title_elem = fishery.find('td', data-content_='Fishery')
    tonnage_elem = fishery.find('td', data-content_='Tonnage')
    if None in (title_elem, tonnage_elem):
        continue
    print(title_elem)
    print(tonnage_elem)
```

The goal of this code is to try to extract the title of the fishery from the following html:

```
<td data-content="
                Fishery
                



            ">
                <a title="AAFA and WFOA North Pacific albacore tuna" href="https://fisheries.msc.org/en/fisheries/aafa-and-wfoa-north-pacific-albacore-tuna/@@view">
                    AAFA and WFOA North Pacific albacore tuna
                </a>
            </td>
```

Specifically, python thinks that data-content_ is an operation when it isn't. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the hyphen character is an operation; Python is indeed attempting to interpret it.  In order to pass it through literally to Beautiful Soup, try explicitly passing it in the `attrs` arg instead of as a keyword argument.

```py
results = soup.find(id='results-body')

fisheries = results.find_all('tr', class_='geo-feature fishery')

for fishery in fisheries:
    title_elem = fishery.find('td', attrs={'data-content': 'Fishery'})
    tonnage_elem = fishery.find('td', attrs={'data-content': 'Tonnage'})
    if None in (title_elem, tonnage_elem):
        continue
    print(title_elem)
    print(tonnage_elem)
```

Reference:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

> The keyword arguments
>
> Any argument that’s not recognized will be turned into a filter on one of a tag’s attributes.

So, the keyword argument ends up as an attribute filter, but it is not a string literal until Python puts it into the kwargs dict (under the hood).  By passing it in `attrs`, you'll send it to the same place (because of how `.find()` interprets its arguments), but since it is quoted as a string in your code, Python will not attempt to interpret the `-` character as an operator any more.

Note that the `class_` keyword argument is a convenience that Beautiful Soup provides since `class` is a reserved word (much like `-` is an operator), and filtering by class is a common operation.  Beautiful Soup can't know all the attributes in use and so it can't provide a convenience method for every reserved/interpretable sequence; the underscore trick won't work for arbitrary reserved words, only `class`.

Reference:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

> Searching by CSS class
>
> It’s very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but the name of the CSS attribute, “class”, is a reserved word in Python. Using class as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error. As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword argument class_